# Implementing custom malloc() able to track allocation locations in C++

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a custom memory management system in C++ for tracking memory allocations. I have a macro which I use when allocating memory, like this:

```
void *p=MALLOC(1024);
```

This macro calls a function to allocate memory, but also allocates some additional memory for memory tracking information. In this memory tracking info I store information about `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__FUNCTION__` so that I know where the allocation occurred (in case there's a leak). However, I want to reduce the size of this memory tracking info and for each allocation would like to store a single pointer which contains this info instead of separate pointer to `__FILE__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__`. So I thought about having the macro defined something like this:

```
struct malloc_info
{
    malloc_info(const char *file_, const char *func_, unsigned line_)
        :file(file_)
        ,func(func_)
        ,line(line_)
        {}
    const char *file;
    const char *func;
    const unsigned line;
};
#define MALLOC(size__) {static const malloc_info s_info(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__); my_custom_malloc(size__, s_info);}
```

However, this doesn't enable the syntax I used above for memory allocation (void *p=MALLOC(1024);). To enable the syntax I was thinking of using a template function to get the malloc_info for each MALLOC() call and do the static allocation of malloc_info within the template function, but I don't know any robust way to instantiate the function for each call. I could use `__LINE__` as template argument but you could have two MALLOC() calls on the same line and I have heard people having issues passing `__LINE__` as template argument anyway, e.g. this wouldn't work:

```
template<unsigned line>
static const malloc_info &get_malloc_info(const char *file_, const char *func_, unsigned line_)
{
    static const malloc_info s_info(file_, func_, line_);
    return s_info;
}
#define MALLOC(size__) my_custom_malloc(size__, get_malloc_info<__LINE__>(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__))
```

Previously I just constructed a string literal which contained the location information about malloc location and stored pointer to this string, e.g.

```
#define MALLOC(size__) my_custom_malloc(size__, __FILE__" ("STR(__LINE__)") - "__FUNCTION__)
```

However, when I ported this code from MSVC to gcc, `__FUNCTION__` isn't string literal anymore (but statically allocated c-string in function scope) thus I can't create concatenated string like this.

So anyone got any suggestions how to go about this?

Thanks, Jarkko

Comment: You shouldn't worry about the memory cost for a DEBUG version of malloc(). (In DEBUG mode, you actually want to use up memory so you can test that condition.) In any case, creating individual strings for each allocation is very likely to use more space than you save by just keeping 12 bytes for each allocation (2 pointers at 4 each, plus 4 for an int; unless you are in 64-bit mode, where its 24 bytes).

Comment: Right, since this is debug only it's not major issue, but it would be still nice to be able to reduce the overhead. The memory info size must be 16-byte aligned and I already have 2 pointers + uint allocated for other purposes so adding two pointers instead of one  adds 100% and 50% to the overhead for 32- and 64-bit builds respectively.

Comment: But you are not accounting for the string literals created by concatenating strings. Each literal includes the file, function and line number which almost certainly takes more space than the additional per-allocation space.

Comment: I wasn't talking about concatenated strings but storing malloc_info structure for each malloc() instance which holds pointers to the string literals, which doesn't create new strings (see my first example above). Just to be clear, the original implementation of using string concatenation isn't good idea due to extra space you mentioned.

Comment: OK, I read closer, sorry. The static local struct method still allocates just as many bytes as storing the data with the allocation, with three differences: 1) one allocation per site, rather than one per-allocation, 2) potentially that struct must also to be aligned, wasting more space, and 3) the memory is statically allocated instead of dynamically allocated. Your custom allocator could take them as parameters and create whatever struct was needed and store the data as efficiently as desired. It could potentially even do better if it grouped by file and/or method.

Comment: There can be quite a few allocations done at each site (e.g. list::push_back() allocates memory for each element in a single site) so it would be generally good idea to try to optimize for this case. Allocating the site info statically at the site makes most sense to me. The site info allocated statically doesn't need to be aligned since it doesn't precede the allocated memory block in memory (only the pointer to it does).

Comment: This question seems to be about C++98. Otherwise, lambdas

Comment: Ah yes, lambda would do the trick. I just like this still to work with some older compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit hacky but I could have robust implementation by using `__COUNTER__` macro instead of `__LINE__` that is passed as a template function argument to ensure that the function is instantiated for each call site. `__COUNTER__` isn't part of the C++ standard (to my knowledge) but it is supported by compilers I'm targeting currently (gcc & MSVC). So what could work is this:

```
struct alloc_site_info
{
  alloc_site_info(const char *filename_, const char *funcname_, unsigned line_)
    :filename(filename_)
    ,funcname(funcname_)
    ,line(line_)
  {}
  const char *filename;
  const char *funcname;
  unsigned line;
};

template<unsigned>
static const alloc_site_info &get_alloc_site_info(const char *filename_, const char *funcname_, unsigned line_)
{
  static const alloc_site_info s_info(filename_, funcname_, line_);
  return s_info;
}

#define MALLOC(bytes__) my_alloc(bytes__, get_alloc_site_info<__COUNTER__>(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__));
```

It's not the prettiest implementation but the only working solution I'm currently aware of.